# rename command Debian server

Tags: regex, perl, ubuntu, debian

The following worked on my old server (Ubuntu)

```
rename -n 's/(.*)\/.*\./$1\/$1./' */*
```

but not on my new server (Debian).

I'm guessing the new server is using the Perl `rename`. How would one convert the above to work the same with Perl `rename`? All it was meant to do is rename files in a folder so that the name starts with the name of the parent folder (removing any name before the last dot in the original filename).  Thus, `include/anything.h` would become `include/include.h`.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rename command that is part of the `util-linux` package, won't work.

You need to run :

```
# apt install rename
```

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result that contains `Perl script, ASCII text executable` and not containing `ELF`, then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
# update-alternatives --set rename /usr/bin/file-rename
```

Comment: which means: if you port or maintain a DEB package, _and this package indeed uses `rename`,_ you should add the 'rename' package to its build-dependencies (starting with Debian/Buster). This will also automatically ensure the `update-alternatives` is performed